# Are continuous weakly $p$-harmonic maps smooth?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions, regularity-theory-of-pdes

It is well-known that continuous weakly harmonic maps are smooth. Is the same thing true for $p$-harmonic maps (for $p>2$)?

More specifically: Let $M,N$ be smooth Riemannian manifolds, and let $f \in W^{1,p}(M,N)$ be a continuous map, which is also weakly $p$-harmonic. Is $f$ smooth?

I am in particularly interested in the case where the source and target have the same dimension $d$, and $p=d$.

I am somewhat aware that the regularity theory for $p$-harmonic maps is less developed in general compared to the classic $p=2$ case, but I could not find a specific reference discussing this specific question.

Comment: Certainly not $C^\infty$ smooth, if that's what you are asking; could you quantify "smooth" here?

Comment: Yes, I meant $C^{\infty}$. $C^1$ would also be interesting, though usually if something like that is $C^1$ then it can be boosted to $C^{\infty}$. (Maybe I am too hasty here, we might need to have a-priori estimates on the derivatives for this such a boosting to be possible). Anyway, I would be happy to see any reference which contains a non-$C^{\infty}$ example, or to see a description, if there is a simple example.

Comment: WIth $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $N=\mathbb{R}^1$, the best regularity for $p>2$ is $C^{1,\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ depends on $p$ and tends to $1/3$ as $p\to\infty$. See [Iwaniec-Manfredi](https://eudml.org/doc/39381). Generally, $C^{1,\alpha}$ holds for $p$-harmonic maps between Euclidean spaces, too. I'll see if I can find a reference for general manifolds.